# Using induction for an easy proof for formal languages

Tags: induction, formal-languages

I am having trouble to understand the way of using a induction for the following example:

> Let $\Sigma \overset{\Delta} = \{a, b\}$ and $S_1 \overset{\Delta} = \{a^n \mid n \in \Bbb N\}$. Prove using induction that $$\forall w \in \Sigma^* . w \in S_1 \to \big( w = \lambda \lor (\forall \ 1 \le i \le |w| . (w)_i = a) \big) .$$

How to do that?
Any help is upvoted.

Comment: Does $(w)_i$ mean the i'th symbol in $w$?

Comment: yep, I think so

Comment: Consider a formal proof via induction over $m:=|w|$. I'm not sure, though, if you need induction here anyway.

Comment: nono induction is not needed. But I need to learn how to do it using induction.

Answer (score 1):

Induction on the *lenght* $n$ of the string.

i) $n=1$ : then $|w|=1$. But also $w=a$, by definition of $S_1$, and thus $(w)_1=a$.

ii) $n \to n+1$ : then $|w|=n+1$. But also $w=w'a$, where $|w'|=n$.

By induction hypotheses : $(w)_i=(w')_i=a$, for $1 \le i \le n$ and also $(w)_{n+1}=a$, and thus :

> $(w)_i=a$, for $1 \le i \le n+1=|w|$.

---

As already commented by others, the use of induction here is quite "excessive".

We rely on the fact that, by definition of $S_1= \{a^n \mid n \in \mathbb N \}$, $(w)_i=a$, for any $i \le |w|$.

Thus, we already have the result, i.e.

> $w \ne λ \to ∀i \ ((1≤i≤|w|) \to (w)_i=a))$.